# Travel Agency - A Zebra Puzzle (Einstein's Riddle) variation

Tags: logical-deduction, logic-grid

You can play it online here: https://www.brainzilla.com/logic/zebra/travel-agency/

```
|            | Woman #1 | Woman #2 | Woman #3 | Woman #4 | Woman #5 |
|------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|
| purse      |          |          |          |          |          |
| name       |          |          |          |          |          |
| age        |          |          |          |          |          |
| profession |          |          |          |          |          |
| country    |          |          |          |          |          |
| duration   |          |          |          |          |          |
```

Five women are side by side booking a travel in a travel agency. Each one is traveling to an different country. Follow the clues to discover where each one is going.

- purse: blue, green, red, white, yellow
- name: Ana, Glenda, Jessie, Lara, Rose
- age: 24, 26, 28, 30, 32
- profession: biologist, hostess, judge, nurse, singer
- country: China, Egypt, Italy, Mexico, Peru
- duration: 5 days, 10 days, 15 days, 20 days, 25 days

Clues:

1. The Singer is at the third position.
2. The woman traveling for 20 days is somewhere between the woman who is going to Peru and the owner of the Blue purse, in that order.
3. Ana is exactly to the left of the Biologist.
4. The 32 years old is going to see the Sahara.
5. The owner of the White purse is exactly to the right of the woman traveling to visit Machu Picchu.
6. Glenda is somewhere to the right of the woman who has the Green purse.
7. The person wearing the White purse is somewhere between the 30 years old woman and the owner of the Blue purse, in that order.
8. The 24 years old woman is going to visit an Aztec pyramid.
9. The woman wearing the White purse is somewhere to the left of the yougest woman.
10. The traveler going to Italy is exactly to the right of the woman traveling for 20 days.
11. The person who is going to travel for 25 days has the Red purse.
12. The Judge is in the first position.
13. The Nurse is exactly to the right of the woman who is going to travel for 20 days.
14. The Hostess is somewhere between Lara and the woman who has the Blue purse, in that order.
15. In the second position is the woman that is going to travel for 15 days.
16. Rose has the Green purse.
17. The woman who is traveling for less than a week is exactly to the left of the 32 years old woman.
18. The person traveling for 5 days is 28.
19. The Blue purse owner is somewhere between the 30 years old woman and the owner of the Yellow purse, in that order.

Edit: fixed the 5th clue from "The owner of the White purse is going to visit Machu Picchu" to "The owner of the White purse is exactly to the right of the woman traveling to visit Machu Picchu".

Comment: I'd like to revert to the original puzzle, which was solvable and which I *solved*.

Comment: @pb8330 this last had two solutions though

Comment: But... why did Jamie change the fifth clue ? @Beast

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From 1, 12 & 15

From 18 & 17, women of age 28 & 32 are in adjacent positions in that order.
From 9 there are at-least two women on left of youngest woman and one of them is of age 30.
Hence youngest woman is in position 3, women of age 28 & 32 are in position 4 & 5 respectively, woman at position 4 is traveling for 5 days and woman at position 2 has white purse and is of age 26.
From 4 , 5 & 8 it also follows that woman at position 5 is visiting Sahara, woman at position 1 is visiting Machu Picchu & woman at position 3 is visiting Aztec Pyramid.

From 10 & 2 woman traveling for 20 days is not at extreme left or extreme right. So woman traveling for 20 days is at position 3.
From 10 & 13 woman at position 4 is a nurse and is going to Italy.
From 14 it follows that hostess is not on extreme right and is therefore at position 2 & the name of the woman at position 1 is Lara. Which leaves position 5 to biologist.

From 19 & 2 it follows that woman with blue purse is in position 4 and woman in position 5 has a yellow purse.

From 16 it follows that the name of the woman at position 3 is Rose and she has a green purse. which leaves the color of the purse of woman at position 1 as red.

From 11 it follows that woman 1 is traveling for 25 days and thus woman 5 is traveling for 10 days.
Also from 2 it follows that Ana is at position 4, following which Glenda is in position 5, leaving position 2 to Jessie.

Replacing the travel destinations by the country name and assigning the remaining country name as the destination of woman at position 2 the final result is.

> [image: Please see the following image For step-wise grid status]

Comment: I fixed the image for you

Answer (score 4):

Using the offline version of [this](http://www.jsingler.de/apps/logikloeser) Java app, I filled in the following logic grid:

> [image: logic grid]

And found that

> The first woman is going to China, the second to Peru, the third to Mexico, the fourth to Italy and the fifth to Egypt.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the website-confirmed answer:

> [image]

CSV:

> ```
> |            | Woman #1 | Woman #2 | Woman #3 | Woman #4 | Woman #5 |
> |------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|
> | purse      |   red    |  white   |   green  |   blue   |  yellow  |
> | name       |   Lara   |  Jessie  |   Rose   |    Ana   |  Glenda  |
> | age        |    30    |    26    |    24    |    28    |    32    |
> | profession |   judge  |  hostess |  singer  |   nurse  |biologist |
> | country    |   Peru   |  China   |  Mexico  |   Italy  |   Egypt  |
> | duration   |    25    |    15    |    20    |    5     |     10   |
> ```

HOWEVER, @dcfyj points out in the comments that Machu Picchu isn't in China, it's in Peru. So therefore the person with the white purse should be going to Peru. However that doesn't work, so I think the website has made a mistake.

I was timed and it took me 13 minutes. Adding Step by Step now

STEP 1: Back to Basics

First we should find the basic clues, the definites. The basic clues here are:

> 1, 12 and 15

GRID:

```
|            | Woman #1 | Woman #2 | Woman #3 | Woman #4 | Woman #5 |
|------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|
| purse      |          |          |          |          |          |
| name       |          |          |          |          |          |
| age        |          |          |          |          |          |
| profession |  judge   |          |  singer  |          |          |
| country    |          |          |          |          |          |
| duration   |          |    15    |          |          |          |
```

STEP 2: Infermiera

We know from the common statement in 10 and 13 that the Nurse is going to Italy. We also therefore know from statement 2 she is either person 4 or 5.

STEP 3: Queen Ana IV

From Step 2 we can work out that Ana is the fourth person. We know she is left of the biologist, meaning she can't be in fifth. We also know that the hostess is between someone from statement 14, so she can't be 5th.

So now there are two possibilities:

- judge - biologist - singer - hostess - nurse
- judge - hostess - singer - nurse - biologist

If we go with the first option, then that means that the fifth person has to have a blue purse from rule 14, but that contradicts rule 19 so the correct way is the second:

GRID:

```
|            | Woman #1 | Woman #2 | Woman #3 | Woman #4 | Woman #5 |
|------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|
| purse      |          |          |          |          |          |
| name       |          |          |          |   Ana    |          |
| age        |          |          |          |          |          |
| profession |  judge   |  hostess |  singer  |   nurse  |biologist |
| country    |          |          |          |          |          |
| duration   |          |    15    |          |          |          |
```

STEP 4: Lara Judges a Nurse in the Blue

Lara is person 1 from rule 14, and blue purse must be person 4 from 2 and 19. Rules 2 and 13 also mean that person 3 travels for 20 days.

WILL HAVE TO FINISH TOMORROW, SLEEP CALLS US ALL, EVEN GERBILS...

Comment: We appear to have different conclusions ! I'll recheck mine later.

Comment: @pb8330 Unfortunately for you I know mine is correct, as the website told me. Sorry :)

Comment: Since when is Machu Picchu in China?

Comment: @dcfyj hmmm.... since the website told me that

Comment: Sorry about that mistake. Just fixed the 5th clue. Thanks for pointing it out @pb8330.

Comment: Hold on, why can't the original clues (i.e. white purse visiting Machu Picchu) work ? My answer seems to fit. (Am I being dippy ?)

Comment: @pb8330 Machu Picchu is in Peru not China

Comment: Right, but I managed to fill my grid in with that original clue. The only differences between our answers are the countries that the first two women are visiting. They both fit the other clues, do they not ?

Comment: @pb8330 I can't really tell what your answer is without a graph like mine...

Comment: *Graph* ? Should I make a grid ?

Comment: @pb8330 thats the one :P

Comment: The first two countries just need to be swapped, and that's my answer.

Comment: @pb8330 if i finish my step by step, may take a while, sleeping soon, then i can see...

Comment: OK, I'll ask @Jamie - good night :)

Comment: Will look into this tomorrow, @pb8330. Thanks again for your time pointing out mistakes.